# How to build and print in Python - GEKKO a list of optimized values generated by loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gekko

I have an Objective function with four parameters to be optimized (n1, n2, n3 and n4). This optimization should be done in a loop "for T in T" as the Objective function is a function of T. As a result I get for each T, a set of parameters. How can I build and print individualized lists containing T, n1, n2, n3 and n4?

I have tried different ways of "print", inside the loop and outside of it. I have also searched for examples here and in the GEKKO's documentation but it is still a challenge to me. Thanks in advance.

```py
import math
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

T = np.arange(1, 10, 2)
for T in T:
    A = 3/(T**2)
    B = 20-T**2
    C = 3+T
    D = T

    mA = A-T*C
    mB = B-T*D

    # Minimization routine

    from gekko import GEKKO
    m = GEKKO()

    # Variables to be minimized:
    n1, n2, n3, n4 = [m.Var() for i in range(4)]
    var = [n1, n2, n3, n4]

    # Initial values:
    n0 = [3,2,3,3]
    nL = np.ones(len(n0))*10**-10
    nU = np.ones(len(n0))*10**10
    for i,x in enumerate(var):
        x.value = n0[i]
        x.lower = nL[i]
        x.upper = nU[i]

    nt = m.Intermediate(n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)

    # Objective:
    m.Obj(T*A*mA + B*mB + C*D/nt)
    # Set global options
    m.options.IMODE = 3

    # Solve minimization
    m.solve()

    print(n1, n2, n3, n4)
    print(str(n1.value), str(n2.value), str(n3.value), str(n4.value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to [export data from Python as shown here](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonDataAnalysis). You need to get the results into a 2 dimensional list, NumPy array, or Pandas data frame. The following are modifications to your original script if you need to get the values into a form that Excel can open, such as a CSV file. This script uses NumPy to write the file.

```py
import math
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

T = np.arange(1, 10, 2)
z = [None]*len(T)
for j,T in enumerate(T):
    A = 3/(T**2)
    B = 20-T**2
    C = 3+T
    D = T

    mA = A-T*C
    mB = B-T*D

    # Minimization routine

    from gekko import GEKKO
    m = GEKKO()

    # Variables to be minimized:
    n1, n2, n3, n4 = [m.Var() for i in range(4)]
    var = [n1, n2, n3, n4]

    # Initial values:
    n0 = [3,2,3,3]
    nL = np.ones(len(n0))*10**-10
    nU = np.ones(len(n0))*10**10
    for i,x in enumerate(var):
        x.value = n0[i]
        x.lower = nL[i]
        x.upper = nU[i]

    nt = m.Intermediate(n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)

    # Objective:
    m.Obj(T*A*mA + B*mB + C*D/nt)
    # Set global options
    m.options.IMODE = 3

    # Solve minimization
    m.solve(disp=False)

    result = [T]
    for x in var:
        result.append(x.value[0])
    z[j] = result

zn = np.array(z)
np.savetxt('z.txt',zn,delimiter=',',comments='',header='T,n1,n2,n3,n4')
```

[image: Result Table in Excel]

Answer (score 1):

Gekko is built for time-varying systems so the results are returned as a list. Steady state optimization only returns one value so you'll need to access the first element of the `value` property. Try accessing an individual result with `n1.value[0]`. The `T` value is a numpy array so you can access the values with T[0], etc. Try something like the following at the end of your program script:

```py
    # Solve minimization
    m.solve(disp=False)

    result = [T]
    for x in var:
        result.append(x.value[0])
    print(result)
```

It creates an initial list with the value of `T` and then appends the other values. I set the option `disp=False` to not show the solver output. The modified script produces these results:

```
[1, 3457333826.4, 3457319622.4, 3457333826.4, 3457333826.4]
[3, 2482924773.0, 2482917643.6, 2482924773.0, 2482924773.0]
[5, 2201591127.3, 2201587887.6, 2201591127.3, 2201591127.3]
[7, 2105335286.6, 2105331976.7, 2105335286.6, 2105335286.6]
[9, 1630154729.7, 1630153615.7, 1630154729.7, 1630154729.7]
```

It appears that all of the parameter values are equal for this problem and they don't have a connection to the other equations except for calculation of `nt` and the objective term `C*D/nt`.

Comment: Dear John, thank you so much for your help. I am still having hard time with this issue because what I really need is, outside the loop, be able to obtain the n1 array, the n2 array. Once I get these arrays I would export it to excel but this I have already learnt how to do. The problem is really to be able to get as array n1(T), n2(t)...

Comment: Another possible solution is to use the results file ```results.csv``` that is located in the run directory (```m._path``` or ```m.open_folder()```). It is a CSV file that contains all of the results.

Comment: I'll post another solution here on getting the values into a table in Excel with a CSV file.